# How to get rid of black substance in render?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

Okay, so I decide to follow a tutorial on making realistic clouds. I made some modifications to a cube and noticed that in rendered view a black substance appears withing the cube. I've seen this before when making fire. Is this a glitch or there is something wrong with my gpu? I was using Eevee to render. the screenshots below show the node structure that i used and the cube too.[the cloud in rendered view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqGxC.png)[image: the node structure in the shade editor for the cloud][image]

Comment: Hello maybe share your object and also the link to the tutorial?

Comment: @moonboots I'll never understand why everybody wants to fill the servers with blend files when the reason for the issue is clearly visible in screenshots ;)

Comment: because it's often more convenient to find the problem with the file ;)

Answer (score 6):

Even without knowing the tutorial I'm quite sure the output of the *Gradient Texture* node should not be plugged into the *Color* input of the *Principled Volume*.  Or at least not exclusively there.

Without an input for the *Density*, the cube will have a homogenously dense volume filling the whole cube. Only the color you've plugged in makes a part of it look black and the other part white, here just a simple shperical gradient:

[image: density homogenous]

If you instead plug the *Fac* output (*Color* is not necessary since you just need a greyscale value for the density) of the *Gradient Texture* in the *Density* input, black will become a density of 0, and white a density of one - so that the black part is not visible:

[image: density by texture]

I don't know the tutorial, but if the setup you have is the one shown there, it is wrong. And if they use *Color* instead of *Fac*, I also don't know if there is a special reason for that later on but usually it should not matter too much.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: the tutorial had the same settings as yours, i just missed it, nodes can be a handful for a beginner.